# Looking for api call to send ERC20 token over eth-wallet

Tags: metamask, etherscan

I use metamask and etherscan api to get the info when a specific ERC-20 token is sent to my wallet. I would like to use API to send a specific ERC-20 token back to a given public key over API from node backend but can't find any way to do so with the current APIs.

Can this be achieved over ETH wallet or any other way?

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved with metamask.

Comment: MetaMask is a browser plugin and thus not suitable for use from a backend node.js backend. But web3.js is sufficient.